# Flow - How can I return an HTMLInputElement using getElementById without checking instanceof?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

If I have an `<input>` with id `asdf`, and I run `const asdf = document.getElementById('asdf')`, Flow assumes that `asdf` is an `HTMLElement` rather than an `HTMLInputElement`. I need `asdf` to be an `HTMLInputElement` so that Flow will let me call `value` on it, as `value` isn't guaranteed to exist on `HTMLElement`s but is on `HTMLInputElement`s. So to make this work, I have to check `if (asdf instanceof HTMLInputElement)`, then run the code I want.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Simply cast it if you're sure that `#asdf` is an input?

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for your response -- how do I do that? The "typecasts" section in the docs doesn't seem to cover this case.

Comment: Ah, do you mean something like `const asdf: HTMLInputElement = (document.getElementById('asdf'): any)`?

Comment: I think `instanceof` is the correct approach. Casting to `any` will break if someone changes your HTML so that `asdf` is not `<input>`. By checking with `instanceof` you can as least log an explanation. https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/61#issuecomment-145196900

Answer (score -3):

If 'asdf' can be other than 'input' and you need to be sure:

```
const asdf = document.getElementById('asdf')

if (asdf.tagName === 'INPUT') {
    //your code...
}
```